# Crashlytics not showing the logs

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, crash-log

In my android project I'm using Crashlytics to get the app crash reports.I have also added the logs to see it in my dashboard.For adding logs I've used

```
Crashlytics.log (Log.ERROR, TAG, message);
```

So when I run the app for testing,and open the activity where I've added the Crashlytics log statements ,the logs were generated for the first time .I can see them on the dashboard. But when I again open the same activity ,I'm not able to see the new logs generated . I read [here](https://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions) that if the logs are not seen on the dashboard then restart the app.I did that ,but still couldn't see the logs on the dashboard,my dashboard only shows the logs which were generated for the first time.I also tried testing my app on different device but it still doesn't show on the dashboard.Can somebody please help me in solving this issue .Why am I not able to see all non-fatal logs on my dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

IF this doesn't produce errors you have to wait for logs registered on your dashboard in free account

Comment: have been waiting for an hour ,but still can't see any logs.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Firebase here.

`Crashlytics.log (Log.ERROR, TAG, message);` will only be displayed if there is also a non-fatal - `Crashlytics.logException(e);` or fatal exception. We prioritize capturing exceptions (fatal or non-fatal) over logs so if you log the value immediately before the exception, depending on the size of the log, it may not be recorded. This is because we think capturing the exception is more important than the log.

Comment: Thanks for the information ,but would like to know if there's any way to capture the logs even if exception doesn't occur ?

Comment: Nope, you would need to use a different event/analytics tracker for that.